# Looking for pointers to help construct sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've got a table in an Oracle 11g database that is similar to the following:

```
process_times:
--------------------------------------------
machine_id | load_id | start_time | end_time
```

some example records might look like this:

```
process_times:
----------------------------------------------------------------
machine_id | load_id | start_time          | end_time
----------------------------------------------------------------
220        | 25      | 06/24/2012 04:29:00 | 06/25/2012 04:42:38
187        | 23      | 06/22/2012 14:41:00 | 06/24/2012 00:34:32
187        | 18      | 06/20/2012 11:57:00 | 06/20/2012 23:53:51
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return a relation with an attribute representing the down time between loads of each machine. By down time I mean the time in between each end_time and the following start_time for a given machine.

So for the above example I'd get a result like:

```
result:
----------------------
machine_id | down_time
----------------------
220        |  0
187        |  (06/22/2012 14:41:00 - 06/20/2012 23:53:51) -- the actual result, I wrote it like this to be more clear
```

I've been tinkering with this for a good chunk of the afternoon and it's only a pre requisite to the query I'm really trying to write so I figured I would post to see if anyone had any pointers to get me heading in the right direction.

**Edit** Another constraint that I should mention is that I need to have the result list the individual down times for each machine and not just the total amount of down time over a given period of time.

Comment: @Oded updated with the database ~ sorry!

Comment: I think it would be easier to compute the "uptime" by simply finding the row-wise time deltas, then subtract that from the total time (which might be something like `min(start_time) - max(end_time)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  You need to start by getting the prev/next record and then doing the subtraction.  Fortunately, Oracle has the lead/lag functions for this.

So:

```
select machine_id, (lastend - start_time) as down_time
from (select pt.*,
             lag(end_time, 1) over (partition by machine_id order by end_time) as lastend
      from process_time pt
     ) pt
where lastend is not null
```

This finds the previous record with and end time and then calculates the downtime.

Comment: This is beautiful. I think this may work - I have to translate it from my simplified example back to the real deal to see if it works but either way thanks for showing be about lead/lag.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested, but following from my comment, this sould get you the uptime.  The downtime is easily derived from the uptime if you know the total time window.

```
SELECT machine_id, SUM(joblen) AS uptime
FROM (
    SELECT machine_id, (end_time - start_time) AS joblen
    FROM process_times
    )
GROUP BY machine_id
```

In fact, the subquery might not even be necessary, you may be able to do something like

```
SELECT machine_id, SUM(end_time - start_time) AS uptime
FROM process_times
GROUP BY machine_id
```

I don't know though.

From there, you might do something like:

```
SELECT machine_id, (lifetime - uptime) AS downtime
FROM (
    SELECT machine_id, 
        SUM(end_time - start_time) AS uptime, 
        (min(start_time) - max(end_time) as lifetime
    FROM process_times
    GROUP BY machine_id
    )
```

Anyway, this is a rough outline of how I'd approach it, it almost definitely won't be a cut and paste-type answer.

Comment: this is a really good approach to the problem - unfortunately I need to preserve the individual down times so the client can view how long the machine was idle for in between uses. I'll update the question to clarify.